# Android Studio activity_main.xml design editor not letting me drag and drop anything...?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Title says it all, image as follows. Let me know what you can do!

#### Image 1. Trying to drop a widget:

[image]

#### Image 2. Not dropping the widget:

[image]

#### Image 3. Xml file content

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us the full XML file content ? It says that you have rendering problems, they should be highlighted on the XML.

Comment: First You  select component then  after click on desing area in xml file. automatically drag your componets

Comment: It won't work as he has some rendering problems.

Comment: first remove that -1px error then you will be able to do that

Comment: @MalteseFalcon https://imgur.com/RjnLZjc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the xml view and change the `-1px` to something positive. Your rendering problem will be fixed and then you will be allowed to drag and drop views.

The message also says *(2 similar errors)*. Fix those too before trying to drag and drop views onto the layout.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything with -1. I have no idea where this error is coming from. https://imgur.com/RjnLZjc

Comment: share the xml for the layout

Comment: You are in the design tab select text tab from the bottom. Right below the toolbox from where you are picking the views to drop

Comment: I already shared that in the first comment, here it is again https://imgur.com/RjnLZjc

Comment: Yes it is not there in your XML. It looks like it is inherited. Check the styles and themes used in the XML and see if they were tampered with.

Comment: Have you tried to clean / rebuild ? Sometimes it can fix the thing. I don't see anything that could cause problems in your XML files...